# Multi-Processing Subprocess call and Pyautogui Issue

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess, pyautogui

I am trying to use python to multi-process the call of a program using the subprocess command and make various clicks on the program's GUI using the pyautogui library. If I substitute out the path to an executable program that I am trying to use with another path to some arbitary program, in this case the arduino application, it seems to work just fine. However, when I call the program I would like to click on, the clicks simply don't happen.  Has anyone else encountered a similar problem before when trying to use pyautogui coupled with the multiprocessing library? Also note that I had to multi-process in this situation due to the global interpreter lock that happens if this code were to be executed sequentially (the clicks would not happen unless the subprocess is first terminated and that line of code is considered complete).

```py
# Processes defined for multiprocessing of GUI and clicks

def gui_call_thread():
    subprocess.Popen(["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\arduino.exe"], shell = True)

def mouse_clicking_control():
    time.sleep(8) # wait for GUI to load before executing clicks
    pyautogui.click(1076,537)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    pyautogui.click(1065,558)
    time.sleep(0.5) 
    pyautogui.click(1060,643)
    time.sleep(3)
    pyautogui.click(224,110)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    pyautogui.click(249,135)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    pyautogui.click(922,507)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    pyautogui.click(1139,459, clicks = 2)
    print('Finished Clicks') 

def execute_multiprocess():
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        gui_call = multiprocessing.Process(target = gui_call_thread())
        mouse_clicks = multiprocessing.Process(target = mouse_clicking_control())
        gui_call.start()
        mouse_clicks.start()
        mouse_clicks.join() # wait for clicks to complete before exiting
        gui_call.join() # kills gui after clicks complete

# Execute desired functions to run program
execute_multiprocess()
```

Comment: So, you don't want to bother us with details ([mcve]) but are expecting us to guess where the problem could be? That said, mixing multiprocessing and multithreading can make sense, but usually doesn't, so look into that. As a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: My mistake Ulrich, I cleaned up my post and added the code. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Do you realize that multiprocessing is completely unnecessary here?  You could call `gui_call_thread` to launch the app, then call `mouse_clicking_control` to do the automation.  This is a strictly serial task.

Comment: Hi Tim, you are right actually, when I initially did this I was using subprocess.call() which would hang after calling the GUI and the rest of the code wouldn't execute sequentially. I just tried your suggestion and noticed when I use Popen instead it didn't hang this time. For some reason, however, it still won't click for the specific GUI I'm calling, but it works for the arduino GUI as well as others so I'm not sure whats going on.